# Tap location in a UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, core-animation

I have a UIImageView with a UIImage inside set to scale aspect ratio. The image is more tall than wide and there is a transparent region on either side of the UIImageView. How can I convert the tap location of the UIImageView to correct locations inside of the UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the original width and height of the image. divide it with the width and height of the view. multiply the factor `image.size.height/view.frame.size.height` with the `y` you tapped and `image.size.width/view.frame.size.width` with the tapped `x`.